# QUnit.config.semaphore is undefined and so does not affect stop() or start()

Tags: config, semaphore, qunit

QUnit has been used for some time so this has got to be a mistake somewhere on my part but I can't figure out where the problem is:

I am using QUnit 1.12.0 and see this behavior in both IE11 and Chrome 31.0.1650.63

Since the QUnit.config.semaphore value starts off as undefined, the calls to QUnit.stop() and QUnit.start() do not actually decrement or increment the value.

For example, line 488 of qunit-1.12.0.js (which is the first line of the stop() method) is:

```
config.semaphore += count || 1;
```

Because config.semaphore starts off as undefined, this line simply makes config.semaphore a NaN, it never actually increments the value. Therefore, the start() method doesn't have an actual number to test against.

The result is I can call these methods:

```
Qunit.config.autostart = false;
QUnit.stop();
QUnit.stop();
QUnit.test(xxx);
QUnit.start();
```

When I call QUnit.start(), my test is ran. However it should not be ran because I called stop() twice and start() only once.

An example of this is at: http://plnkr.co/edit/pH1SCk2AuXW30wltwS3g?p=preview

The test should *not* run however it does. If you uncomment line 4 of the script.js in the above plnkr site, the test does not run as expected because the QUnit.config.semaphore is initialized to zero instead of being left undefined. However the documentation for QUnit does not include docs for the QUnit.config.semaphore value so I would not expect to modify it.